# daily crash of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse

At least once a day my system comes to a halt.
The mouse can not click and the keyboard cannot enter. 
in fact all i can do is reboot.
I saw on the internet that others have experienced the same problem but nobody seems to have a solution.
The word is that GNOME is the culprit.
Can and how can i change the desktop to KDE please if this is the only way out.
I have suffered this for weeks now and it seems nobody is taking sserious interest in this problem.

Comment: To verify that it's the memory leak you're referring to, open a terminal (press Ctrl + Alt + T) and run `watch free -h`. Shrink the window so that it's just large enough to contain its output. Press Alt + Space and make the window always on top. Put the window out of your way.  When the system freezes next time, look at the **available memory** (not the free memory, which doesn't count things Linux is holding onto but which it can throw away in an instant if an application needs the memory).

Answer (score 4):

There's a known [memory leak](https://fossbytes.com/gnome-3-26-memory-leak-issue-no-fix-ubuntu-18-04/) in [GNOME](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/64) which 18.04 uses, and explains what you heard. Folks have been working on it, and fixes should be completely provided by September.

Changing to KDE will obviate that problem now.

Get to a shell prompt and run `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` then password in. Approve all the dependencies shown, and let it complete.

Logout, then login and choose KDE.

Answer (score 2):

Also you could try xfce, a lightweight desktop environment.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Then, logout, select the desktop on the login screen.

Comment: xfce didn't have all advantage that GNOME and KDE had, despite the fludity of this desktop (and not so bad graphically), GNOME and KDE are better; you got problem with GNOME -> install KDE, and vice versa

Comment: Okay. I was a user rather a fan of Gnome2, but once it added too much flamboyancy (in my opinion!), tried fallback option, eventually settled with Xfce. Comfortable with its static look and behavior.